# Insert all HTML in PHP

Tags: php

This is a simple but tricky question. I strucked in a problem where i am unable to understand how can i warp all of the html code so that it show on backend with PHP value.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fit_link', true );
?>" target="_blank">

<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fit_text', true ); ?>
</a>
```

The problem is when there is no Link and text value retrieved from DB it shows a empty anchor tag in source.
**Just like this:** `<a href="" target="_blank"></a>`

Can anyone please help me to understand that how can i make above code to output when there is value. otherwise it should not show any code in source.

Comment: what about adding an if ( !empty(get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fit_link', true ))) { .... }

Comment: Yes It shows empty value but the problem is HTML. it render without data just like `<a href="" target="_blank">

          </a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use isset() function

```
    <?php
      if(isset($post->ID) && strlen(get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fit_link', true ))>1)
      {
          echo "THE A HREF LINK IS = ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fit_link', true ); //remove this line after testing
        ?>
     <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fit_link', true );?>" target="_blank">
     <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fit_text', true ); ?>
     </a>
    <?php
      }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Can this code will stop output empty link and text in anchor tag on front end?

Comment: Again :( Output `<a href="" target="_blank">

          </a>` code in source

Comment: where is function get_post_meta?? according to my code, if $post->ID is set, then only code will get executed, so the problem is with get_post_meta

Comment: Yes but HTML is around it so it just empty the link and text variable but it show HTML with empty tag `<a href="" target="_blank">

          </a>`

Comment: what value do you get from get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fit_link', true )?? i mean expected value :)

Comment: updated code, pls check and waiting for your feedback

Comment: Fabulous! Worked like charm! Can you please help me understand that how you done this?

Comment: sure :) i added one more condition, if string length of get_post_meta is greater than 1, then execute statements inside if  :) thats it :)

Comment: Good! Yes links are always greater then one character. Thank you so much once again!